# VBA checkbox website interaction

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm currently experiencing a problem with VBA. I'm trying to tick checkbox on an external website. Here is a html snippet that I'm working with:[Html code from external website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeooB.png)

I have redacted any confidential information from the snippet.
Here is my VBA code:

```
Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each ele In elements
        ele.toString

        If ele.Value = "xxx" Then ele.Click

    Next
```

So in this code the `elements`variable is an object and the loop variable ele is not being populated at all. I need to compare that the value in the check box contains value `xxx`. I'm not too experienced  in VBA.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if that works. But in VBA the

```
.Value
```

property of a Checkbox is eighter true or false. The property of the text that is shown is:

```
.Caption
```

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for that. I have tried that and it doesn't change it as it doesn't even go into the loop and i cant find the reason why

Comment: Your code looks as it should work... Do you get an error? Can you post it as well?

Comment: I don't get an error. Not sure if this would affect it but this loop is in another loop. The setup is that i loop through list of urls and than inside this loop I have the 2nd loop that is supposed to go through all the <input> tags in the HTML. however the 2nd loop is not executed when I run the code in debug mode. not sure what causes that

Comment: If the debugger is on the for each statement and at the next step it is after that it would mean that it cannot find an Input-Tag... can you post more code?

Comment: here is most of my code:'    
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim elements, ele
    Dim document As HTMLDocument
    objIE.Visible = True
    For Each ip In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A13").Value
        objIE.navigate ip
        Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each ele In elements.toString
            ele.toString
            If ele.Caption = "xxx" Then ele.Click
        Next '

Comment: This is not really readable but there you have: "For Each ele In elements.toString" instead of "For Each ele In elements".... In the code above it's alright

Comment: Yeah sorry about the state of the code. Thought it would have displayed it better.Yes the .toString was there as i was trying to see if that would change anything, but it didn't :(

Comment: Also delete: Dim document As HTMLDocument (is that even working)?

Comment: I have removed the dim document now. the compiler didn't throw any errors about that. Still no change in the loop situation

Comment: Have you tried my code in the other answer I gave? And sorry I have to ask that are there website URLs in Sheet1 Range A2:A13?

Answer (score 0):

This code is looping properly:

```
Sub test()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim elements, ele

    objIE.Visible = True
    For Each ip In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A13").Value
        objIE.Navigate ip
        Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each ele In elements
            ele.toString
            If ele.Value = "xxx" Then ele.Click
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have ran this code just now and it doesn't go into the loop either. it might be a case that something is not set up in the references?

Comment: Sorry just look while debugging if the variable ip is a string with a Website URL in it

Comment: Since i have the IE visibility set to true I can see the IE going to the specified URL so I don't think that is the problem. The ULRs are referring to an internal IP of a device which has its own HTML structure to perform a reset which we would like to automate as this is a frustrating thing to be doing every so often

Comment: Yes i can see the IP address once in the debug

Comment: Have you added a watch to the object elements? does it have items in it?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by watch. Print the object somewhere? Not sure how to do it in VBA

Comment: Right click on the variable > Add Watch... After that go through the code step by step with F8 and look at the objects properties once it's initialized...

Comment: I have added a watch for both element and ele. Element is n object with no variables under it and ele is empty

Comment: Do the same with ObjIE ^^

Comment: objIE has value of InternetExplorer Ip just the URL

Comment: i've got the impression that everything is fine :) the line "objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")" obviously returns no elements so there maybe is no input-element at the website you're referencing with "ip"... Is it possible that you do not open the site you think you do? ...Otherwise I'm sorry, I have no further input for you (just like your website :) )

Comment: I can see the website opening in IE. The input tag is visible when i go to inspect element. i have noticed that the object that is in element is of type DispHTMLElementCollection if that means anything to you. Thanks :)

Comment: This type is correct. This Object should again contain objects of the type "HTMLInputElement" Named "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" and so on... those are representing all "Input"-Tags in your Website...